# What is the difference between GL_RG8_EXT vs. GL_RG_EXT?

Tags: opengl-es

Any idea what is the difference between both of those formats?
I am using `glTexImage2D` in order to pass UV (chroma) data into a UV texture. In case i am using the first type `GL_RG8_EXT` the output seems all green while it works as expected whenever using `GL_RG_EXT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_RG8` is a 'Sized Internal Format' and can be used only for the internal format parameter of `glTexImage2D`.

`GL_RG` is a 'Base Internal Format' which can be used as a internal format and as a format for `glTexImage2D`.

Checkout this site for all valid formats: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml